# Tomcat startup (web.xml) issue

Tags: java, apache-flex, tomcat

I'm using Tomcat 6 with eclipse web tools to publish an application. When I deploy the j2ee application I'm getting this error via tomcat logs:

```
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;Pñ
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:33 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 443 ms
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor aramark-optima.xml
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert argument: null
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.convert(IntrospectionUtils.java:1005)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.CallMethodRule.end(CallMethodRule.java:523)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1138)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1774)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2930)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:365)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1072)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4377)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/aramark-optima/WEB-INF/web.xml
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert argument: null
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2806)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2832)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1141)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1774)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2930)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:365)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1072)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4377)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert argument: null
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.convert(IntrospectionUtils.java:1005)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.CallMethodRule.end(CallMethodRule.java:523)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1138)
 ... 38 more
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Occurred at line 8 column 19
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig start
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.objectweb.jotm).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/aramark-optima] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:34 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [JotmBatch] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 18, 2010 9:50:34 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [JotmClock] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

This leads me to the web.xml file - which apparently is having issues being parsed. However, when examining the web.xml I don't see anything wrong.

Here is the web.xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <javaee:display-name>BlazeDS</javaee:display-name>
  <javaee:description>BlazeDS Application</javaee:description>
  <context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>f2as.library.file</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>/WEB-INF/f2as/user_classes/dto_formulas_complib.swc</javaee:param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>f2as.library.root</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>com.theriabook.controls.superGridClasses.FormulaBase</javaee:param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>mxmlc.configuration.file</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>/WEB-INF/f2as/mxmlc-flex-config.xml</javaee:param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>f2as.configuration.file</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>/WEB-INF/f2as/flex-config.xml</javaee:param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>f2as.class.path</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>/WEB-INF/f2as/jars</javaee:param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>flex.class.path</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>/WEB-INF/flex/hotfixes,/WEB-INF/flex/jars</javaee:param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <javaee:listener-class>flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession</javaee:listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <javaee:display-name>MessageBrokerServlet</javaee:display-name>
    <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <javaee:param-name>services.configuration.file</javaee:param-name>
      <javaee:param-value>/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml</javaee:param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PdfStreamServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.farata.pdf.StreamPdf</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PageReqServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.farata.pdf.PageRequesterServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <javaee:display-name>fileupload</javaee:display-name>
    <servlet-name>fileupload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.aramark.upload.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <javaee:display-name>filedownload</javaee:display-name>
    <servlet-name>filedownload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.aramark.upload.FileDownloadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PdfStreamServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ppdf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PageReqServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.print</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fileupload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/fileupload/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>filedownload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/download/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>demo3.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>clearbi-compiler-invocation-interceptor</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.cti.compiler.env.web.CompilerInvocationInterceptor</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>clearbi-compiler-invocation-interceptor</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>air</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CrystalReportViewerHandler</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>crystal_image_uri</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>/crystalreportviewers</javaee:param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <javaee:param-name>crystal_image_use_relative</javaee:param-name>
    <javaee:param-value>webapp</javaee:param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You are specifying paths to various files in web.xml. Check if they are all present. I faced similar error when tld files were missing for entries in web.xml.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. Change the initial line "<web-app" to the following

   ```
   <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
   ```
2. Throughout the entire file, remove any of those "javaee:" prefixes.

I had the same problem, I think we both copied the web.xml file from the same source. I can't remember what the source was and it worked for me until now, I don't know what changed.

Comment: I think these (the javaee: prefixes) were set by Eclipse

Comment: I had j2ee but removing that in all places in the web.xml fixed my problem too +1

Comment: Itś 2AM after 3 days and finally this fix my problem ... thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

As everyone mentioned its a problem with web.xml 
the web.xml do gets updated, when you are updating the "User Library" in Eclipse IDE, 
i.e. after downloading respective library jar it updates the web.xml by default.

Immediately you need to restore your web.xml else you would get this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

> SEVERE: Parse error in application
>   web.xml file at
>   jndi:/localhost/aramark-optima/WEB-INF/web.xml

This isn't a valid JNDI lookup.  Where is this spelled out?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error when renaming the project (eclipse changed the web.xml file completely) . Fixed it by restoring.